# Python: Unittest for error on substitution

Tags: python, unit-testing, validation, properties, python-unittest

I want to test whether validation of property work. I don't have a good idea with unittest.
The target class is like this:

```
class SomeClass:pass

class Foo:
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    
    @a.setter
    def a(self, _a):
        assert isinstance(_a, SomeClass), TypeError

class OtherClass:pass

f = Foo()
f.a = OtherClass() # <- I want to test that this raise error.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `assertRaises`

```
from unittest import TestCase

with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    f = Foo()
    f.a = OtherClass()
```

Comment: Thank you to answering question.
However it didn't work. I thought that "f.a = OtherClass()" is not function. 
Can assertRaises work on Assignment operator?

Comment: assertError works if an exception of the type you pass to it is raised. if the assignment raises so the answer is yes.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. Your advice can  work. I thank you again.

Comment: "assert isinstance(_a, SomeClass), TypeError" raises AssertionError. Then I changed into raise statement.